# How do i optimize images for my IOS & Android app?

Tags: android, ios, image, optimization

I have an app currently on IOS and Android which takes in their profile pictures, similar to WhatsApp, but my app is very slow. If there are too many pictures on a page and if I scroll down, it throws me out of the app. I want to know how do I optimize those pictures so that it loads fast and does not take up memory. I want it to be like WhatsApp, fast and efficient.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you loading images from remote url?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the size of the images, if the dimensions are to big(pixels) try making making the pixels ratio smaller, hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes, It's true.

You need to make a thumbnail images on a scroll view.
So that you need to have two images - thumbnail image and full size image.

thumbnail image on a scroll view or list view
full size image on a detail view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).